# Stack-overflow markdown editor math enhancement

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, node.js

I used the markdown editor from here: https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/tree/main

My code look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Markdown Editor</title>
  <!--include Stacks -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/@stackoverflow/stacks/dist/css/stacks.css" />
<!-- include the bundled styles -->
<link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="./node_modules/@stackoverflow/stacks-editor/dist/styles.css"
/>

    <!-- highlight.js is not included in the bundle, so include it as well if you want it -->
    <script src="//unpkg.com/@highlightjs/cdn-assets@latest/highlight.min.js"></script>
    <!--include Stacks -->
    <script src="./node_modules/@stackoverflow/stacks/dist/js/stacks.min.js"></script>
    <!-- include the bundle -->
    <script src="./node_modules/@stackoverflow/stacks-editor/dist/app.bundle.js"></script>
    

</head>


<body>

    <div style="margin:20px; width: 800px;">
    <div id="editor-container"></div>
        <!-- initialize the editor -->
    <script>
        new window.stacksEditor.StacksEditor(
            document.querySelector("#editor-container"),
            "*Your* **markdown** here",
            {}
        );
     </script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, it doesnt have one very important feature - Latex math support. I would like to write simply $\frac{1}{2}$ and produce a fraction. How can I add it?

Comment: At the very least, you need to include MathJax library src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full"

Comment: I added     `<script scr="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full"></script>` a tthe end of head but what next?

Answer (score 0):

If youre current code does not work this is the solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/@stackoverflow/stacks/dist/css/stacks.css" />
    <!-- include the bundled styles -->
    <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="./node_modules/@stackoverflow/stacks-editor/dist/styles.css"
    />
    
    <!-- highlight.js is not included in the bundle, so include it as well if you want it -->
    <script src="//unpkg.com/@highlightjs/cdn-assets@latest/highlight.min.js"></script>
    <!--include Stacks -->
    <script src="/node_modules/@stackoverflow/stacks/dist/js/stacks.min.js"></script>
    <!-- include the bundle -->
    <script src="/node_modules/@stackoverflow/stacks-editor/dist/app.bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        
    <div id="editor-container"></div>
    <script>
        new stacksEditor.StacksEditor(
            document.querySelector("#editor-container"),
            "*Your* **markdown** here",
            {}
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But i did not find any way of using latex with the StackEditor. But i found a website that have a latex editor https://stackedit.io/app.

If you are importing youre script as an external js file instead of using in the body as a  tag. Remember to use defer:

```
<!-- highlight.js is not included in the bundle, so include it as well if you want it -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/@highlightjs/cdn-assets@latest/highlight.min.js" defer></script>
<!--include Stacks -->
<script src="./node_modules/@stackoverflow/stacks/dist/js/stacks.min.js" defer></script>
<!-- include the bundle -->
<script src="./node_modules/@stackoverflow/stacks-editor/dist/app.bundle.js" defer></script>
```